How do we explain the apparent conflict in Matthew 6:7?
Matthew 6:7
But when ye pray, use not vain repetitions, as the heathen do: for they think that they shall be heard for their much speaking.
Matthew 26:44
So He left them, went away again, and prayed the third time, saying the same words.
Luke 6:12
And it came to pass in those days, that he went out into a mountain to pray, and continued all night in prayer to God.

There is no conflict at all between the vain repetition of words and verbose speech in comparison to 1. the fervent, nocturnal vigil in preparation of a significant sending forth and 2. the anguished prayer of one about to suffer betrayal, brutality, sacrificial punishment and death. Down-voted as severely lacking what might be charitably called 'focus'.

1 Thess 5:17: “pray without ceasing,”

There is no 'conflict' at all between the vain repetition of words and verbose speech in comparison to 1. the fervent, nocturnal vigil in preparation of a significant sending forth and 2. the anguished prayer of one about to suffer betrayal, brutality, sacrificial punishment and death.
One is in the mouth of the 'heathen' and the others are pressed from the soul of a selfless worshipper.

Jesus' prayer in Gethsemane presents readers with a challenge, but not for the reason suggested in the OP.  This was no "vain repetition" like chanting a mantra; it was a heartfelt plea of a son to a father. The challenge, of course, is that Jesus would not have prayed such a thing if knew the Cross was his destiny and was always willing to accept the Father's will.
Regarding Luke 6:12, a prayer that continues all night DOES not imply a "vain repetition" or "many words" in the sense meant here. All night prayer vigils can take various forms. Repeating a liturgical formula over and over is only one of them. Babbling on endlessly might be another.  But an all night prayer vigil might also represent long, tearful pleadings to see the "face of God" (Ps. 42) or intimate discussions in which the petitioner seeks God guidance. This seems to have been the case in the OP's example, as well as in Luke 9:28 where Jesus consults with the spirits of Moses and Elijah. It could also take the form of sitting in silence and communing with God.
Conclusions: The supposed contradiction is explained in the case of Matthew 26:44  by the fact that Jesus did not merely repeat a mantra or liturgical formula but engaged in a heartfelt pleading with God. It is explained in the case of Luke 6:12 by the fact long prayer vigils may involve prayerful petitions and conversation with God was well as "much speaking" in the pejorative sense.

Some may see it as arguably, but did Jesus not come to die for everyone’s sins, he predicts his death, going to suffer, raised after 3 days etc….
Begs the Q, how can a mighty person like Jesus who done many miracles not be able to escape, if it was his destiny then why the need for vain pray to be saved.
